# Typescript: How to add property ‘types’ to function returned from React.forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to add additional properties onto the return type of Reacts `forwardRef` function. In this case it's the `types` property. I have it working, but as I am relatively new to Typescript I'm sure there's a better way of doing it (or not 100% sure my implementation is correct).

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  forwardRef,
  ReactNode,
  ForwardRefExoticComponent,
  PropsWithoutRef,
  RefAttributes
} from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

enum Types {
  button = "button",
  a = "a"
}

interface Props extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div"> {
  children?: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  type?: Types;
}

interface Button<T> extends ForwardRefExoticComponent<T> {
  types: typeof Types;
}

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>(
  ({ children, className, type, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div {...props} className={className} ref={ref}>
        {children}
        <div>{type}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
) as Button<PropsWithoutRef<Props> & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>;

Button.types = Types;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Button title="foo" type={Button.types.button}>
        Hello
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Is there a cleaner way of extending the returned type from `forwardRef` to add the `types` property?

Working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-ishizaka-2s8vy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do using forwardRef like this.

But a React ref is actually a ref to a HTML DOM element. 
So, you can use tagName to get the type of tag of the inner component having his ref forwarded (to his parent).

---

**EDIT 2** If you want to add some information to a ref, add it in the attributes, for example:

```
<div ref={ref} data-type="a">something</div>
```

Once you have the ref, get the attribute with `ref.getAttribute("data-type")`

---

Making the component to forward back his ref:

```
const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <input type="text" ref={ref} />);
```

Getting the type:

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      value: this.inputRef.current.value,
      typeOfRef: this.inputRef.current.tagName
    });
  };
```

Displaying it:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Ref - createRef</h1>
        <h3>Value: {this.state.value}</h3>
        <h3>Type: {this.state.typeOfRef}</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Input ref={this.inputRef} />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/bonjour123/pen/bGGQQKG

It should be noted that `createRef` **cannot** (**can**, see edit below) be used in functional components, which, with hooks, are the new recommended way to do things in React. It can nevertheless easily be replaced by a callback passed to the children, and called at the ref creation.

Components declaration

```
const Input = ({ returnBackRef }) => <input type="text" ref={returnBackRef} />;
const Button = ({ returnBackRef, text, handler }) => (
  <button onClick={handler} ref={returnBackRef}>{text}</button>
);
```

The app (functional component):

```
const App = () => {
  let [refTo1, setRefTo1] = React.useState({});
  let [refTo2, setRefTo2] = React.useState({});
  let [info, setInfo] = React.useState({
    val1:"",
    tag1:"",
    val2:"",
    tag2:""
  });

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.error(info);
    setInfo({
    val1:refTo1.value,
    tag1:refTo1.tagName,
    val2:refTo2.textContent,
    tag2:refTo2.tagName
  });    
  };

  return (
    <div >
      <h1>React Ref - createRef</h1>
      <h3>Value1: {info.val1}</h3>
      <h3>Type1: {info.tag1}</h3>

      <h3>Value2: {info.val2}</h3>
      <h3>Type1: {info.tag2}</h3>
      <Input returnBackRef={setRefTo1} />
      <Button
        handler={handleSubmit}
        text={"Submit"}
        returnBackRef={setRefTo2}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[https://codepen.io/bonjour123/pen/VwwVqYR](https://codepen.io/bonjour123/pen/VwwVqYR?editors=1010)

**EDIT** My bad, you can actually use useRef, which is like createRef for functional components. But it's still cool to see how to implement it on another way, isn't it ^^

Comment: fowardRef can be used with functional components

Comment: Yes, I meant createRef.Edited

Comment: The reason I want to add ‘types’ is so I can do: <Button type={Button.types.a} />

Comment: Even with this, you are still rendering a <div>, and not a <a>

Comment: Yes I know - this is just example code. The question was around extending the type returned from forwardRef to support adding the ‘types’ property.

Comment: Ok, see EDIT2 )

Comment: This is to do with Typescript